# Does using a complex object/array as a key work "as expected"?

Tags: javascript, set

I need a set of "complex things", where a "complex thing" is an array of numbers or strings.

Can I use a plain object for this?

Example:

```
var set = {};
set[[1,2]] = 1;
set[[1,2]] = 1;
set[["string", "another string"]] = 1;
set[["string", "another string"]] = 1;
```

Now I expect that there are two key/value pairs in `set`, and testing in Chrome confirms that it is the case.  Is it safe to rely on this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Not at all.

Object keys can *only* be strings or numbers.
Complex objects will be converted to strings by calling `toString()`.

You can see this in the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.2.1):

> Let propertyNameString be ToString(propertyNameValue).

Therefore, `set[ [1,2] ]` is the same as `set["1,2"]`.

Comment: toString() may not be sufficiently reliable, you might want to consider some serializing function instead. Even those may not be good enough as your indexes would still be based on values but not the references of object.